# How to understand this piece of generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics, hadoop, mapreduce

This is the sample code from Hadoop's online tutorial (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html)

```
public class WordCount {
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    // Something here
    }
}
```

In the square brackets, there are `<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>` and the twice appearance of `Text` confuses me.

How do we tell which `Text` it refers to in the actual code since there are two of them with the same name? e.g. when we use `private Text word = new Text();`

A similar code in the same piece is `public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>`.

Comment: Your confusion is unclear to me. The order in which the type arguments are passed matters so why would there be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to know which type refers to what you need to take a look at the documentation/implementation of `Mapper` itself, which you can find [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Mapper.html). The generics are called `K1`, `V1`, `K2` and `V2` internally and are used throughout the class on various occasions. So whenever something takes `K1` as an argument (or returns `K1` for that matter), it is referring to the first type you've "plugged" in. It **basically** (putting inheritance and advanced topics like that aside) is just a simple form of substitution.

By the way: Every (good) IDE should help you out with these matters and infer the correct types you are dealing with automatically.

Comment: No, the first `Text` is referred to as `V1` internally, whereas the second one is referred to as `K2`. The order of the elements does absolutely matters here!

Comment: What I was saying is, value1 is if type `Text` and key2 is of type `Text` as well, right?

Comment: Yes, at least if you define the class in the way described above.